# Should I use -in or -on for this case?

Tags: prepositions

Sentence:

> Professional focused **on** actions that makes the difference **in** the business security. Experience **on** X, Y and Z.

Am I using the correct prepositions there? Any other improvement that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "focus on" is correct - Referring to ["focus on" in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/focus-sth-on-sb-sth)
2. @ difference in the business security, i would omit "the". So it makes the difference in business security".
3. "experience in" is correct - Referring to ["expirienced in" in the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/experienced)